# Nginx proxy cache purge process does not clean up items fast enough for new elements

Tags: nginx, caching

We have a nginx fronting our object storage which caches large objects. Objects are as large as 100GB.  The nginx cache max size is set to about 3.5TB.

When there is a surge of large object requests and disk quickly fills up, nginx runs into out of disk space error. I was expecting the cache manager to purge items based on LRU and make room for the new elements, but that does not happen.

I can reproduce the problem with a simple test case:

Config:

proxy_cache_path  /tmp/cache  levels=1:2   keys_zone=cache_one:256m inactive=2d max_size=16G use_temp_path=off;

Test:

1. Run a request to download a file of 15GB, it is served correctly and stored in cache.
2. Run a second request to download a different file of 10GB, it will fail with something like this:

```
2019/10/04 11:49:08 [crit] 20206#20206: *21 pwritev() "/tmp/cache/9/fa/a301d42ca6e5d4188c38ecf56aa3afa9.0000000001" has written only 221184 of 229376 while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: eos_cache_filer, request: "GET...
2019/10/04 12:07:29 [crit] 21201#21201: *487 pwrite() "/tmp/cache/9/fa/a301d42ca6e5d4188c38ecf56aa3afa9.0000000002" failed (28: No space left on device) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: eos_cache_filer, request:
```

Can I tune some cache_manager parameters to make this work? Is there a way to disable buffering in such case - ideally download should not fail, it should just disable caching and buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Query answered in nginx forum: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,285896